# Inverse for the canonical isomorphism of inner product space with its dual.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space equipped with an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

We know that in this case $V$ is isomorphic to $V^*$ via the map $$f:V \to V^\ast, f(v)=\langle v,\cdot\rangle.$$

I can prove that this is injective and surjective, but what I wanted to know is that what is the inverse of this map explicitly? I couldn't find an answer online. Much of the stuff  I found were proving the bijectivity, but not giving an explicit inverse.

Answer (score 6):

If $V$ is finite-dimensional and $B$ is a basis of $V$ then $V^{\star}$ has a corresponding dual basis $B^\star= \{\delta_b: b \in B\}$, where $\delta_b$ is determined by the requirement that $\delta_{b_0}(b) = \delta_{b,b_0}$ for any $b_0,b \in B$.

Now if $V$ is an inner product space, we may pick $B$ to be orthonormal. The map $f$, which is given in a coordinate-free way by specifying
$$
f(v)(w) = \langle v,w \rangle, \quad \forall v,w \in V.
$$
can be described in a simple concrete manner in terms of such a basis, since it is given by $f(b)=\delta_b$ for all $b \in B$. This also makes the inverse of $f$ easy to describe explicitly.

More generally, if $B$ is any basis of $V$, then we obtain a matrix $C= (c_{b,b'}), b,b' \in B$ where $c_{b,b'} = \langle b,b'\rangle$. Now using the basis to identify $V$ with $\mathbb R^n$, the inner product is identified with the form $\mathbf x_1^\intercal C \mathbf x_2$. If we use $\{e_1,…,e_n\}$ to identify $V$ with $\mathbb R^n$ (the space of column vectors), then $V^\star$ is identified with the corresponding space of row vectors, where the dual basis of $V^\star$  is identified with the standard basis of row vectors.

It follows from this that the map $f$ becomes, in coordinates, $\mathbf x \mapsto \mathbf x^{\intercal}C$. Its inverse is then $\mathbf y \mapsto C^{-t}\mathbf y^\intercal = C^{-1}\mathbf y^{\intercal}$ (because $C$ is symmetric since $\langle-,-\rangle$ is).

However, if $V$ is not finite-dimensional, then if $B$ is a basis of $V$, the functionals in $B^\star$ are still linearly independent and it is still the case that $f(b)=\delta_b$ (so that $f$ is injective) but $B^\star$ is *not* a basis of $V^\star$ so in this case $f$ is not an isomorphism, so of course no  explicit description can be given of an inverse to it. If $\eta \in V^\star$ then it is in the image of $f$ precisely when there exists a vector $v_0 \in V$ such that
$$
\eta(v) = \langle v_0,v\rangle, \quad \forall v\in V.
$$
Moreover, since $f$ is injective, there is at most one vector $v_0$ which satisfies this condition. Thus the criterion for a vector in $V$ to be $f^{-1}(\eta)$ is that
$$
\eta(v) = \langle f^{-1}(\eta),v\rangle, \quad \forall v \in V.
$$
However, giving a characterization $f^{-1}(\eta)$ like this is not the same as giving a closed formula for $f^{-1}$.

The fact that $f$ is only an isomorphism for finite-dimensional $V$, means, heuristically speaking, that there cannot be a nice coordinate-free explicit description of $f^{-1}$ (since then that description would surely give an inverse to $f$ in all cases).

Comment: Do we have something like $\langle f^{-1}, \cdot \rangle = f(\cdot)$ or is it not possible to give any description for $f^{-1}$? @krm2233

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and address this. It is certainly true that if $\eta \in V^*$ then $f^{-1}(\eta)$ satisfies $\eta(v) = \langle f^{-1}(\eta),v \rangle$ for all $v \in V$, but that is just stating explicitly what function $f^{-1}$ is supposed to be the inverse of, so I would not call it a formula for the inverse of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for this. If you have the time I would also be interested in the inverse with respect to chosen bases if that is possible. @krm2233

Comment: added a bit more to the answer -- I hope it isn't too terse!

Comment: Thank you. I'm a bit confused with the basis here, but if $\{e_i\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $\{\varepsilon^i\}$ the dual basis for $V^*$ do I have the following: for \begin{align*}
f(v) &= \langle v,\cdot \rangle \\
&= \left\langle\sum_i v_ie_i, \cdot \right\rangle \\
&= \sum_i v_i \langle e_i, \cdot \rangle \\
&= \sum_i v_i \varepsilon^i \\
\end{align*}

and for $f^{-1}$

\begin{align*}
f^{-1}(\varphi) = \sum_i \varphi(e_i)e_i?
\end{align*} @krm2233

Comment: If you track through the definition, if $v =\sum_{i=1}^n v_i e_i$, then $f(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i f(e_i)$, not $\sum_{i=1}^n v_i\epsilon_i$. Indeed if we use $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ to identify $V$ with $\mathbb R^n$ the space of column vectors), then $V^*$ is identified with the space of row vectors where the dual basis of $V^*$ corresponds to the standard basis of row vectors. If $f(e_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n c^i_j\epsilon_j$ then $c^i_j= f(e_i)(e_j) =\langle e_i,e_j\rangle = c_{ij}=c_{ji}$, and so $f(e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ij} \epsilon_j = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ji}\epsilon_j$.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to the problem is given by the natural identification of a vector space with its double dual.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space.

1. If an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is defined on $V$, we can construct the canonical (coordinate-free) isomorphism
   $$f\colon V\to V^*, v\mapsto \langle v,\cdot\rangle. $$
2. This isomorphism induces a natural inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_*$ on $V^*$, defined by
   $$\langle f(v),f(w)\rangle_*=\langle v,w\rangle.$$
   Intuitively, since there is a bijective correspondence $V\leftrightarrow V^*$, we just translate the inner product from one space to the other.
3. Now forget about this construction, and just consider (as at the beginning) the vector space $V^*$ equipped with the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_*$. Again, there is a natural isomorphism
   $$g\colon V^*\to V^{**}, \alpha\mapsto \langle \alpha,\cdot\rangle_*.$$
   Since $V^{**}$ can be naturally identified with $V$, we end up with an isomorphism (with little abuse of notation)
   $$g\colon V^*\to V$$
   and one can show that actually $g$ is the required inverse of $f$ (it is just a tedious verification, but it is also possible to give a proof of it by some sort of abstract nonsense: the composition $g\circ f$ is an automorphism of $V$ given by a composition of natural isomorphisms; hence by a sort of symmetry argument it must be the identity: otherwise $g\circ f$ would be a somehow preferred automorphism of $V$, which does not make sense).

This construction of $g$ is quite abstract, but it shows that it *is* possible to describe the inverse of $f$ in a coordinate-free way, and it has exactly the same form of $f$.

Fixing an orthonormal basis $B=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ of $V$, the corresponding dual basis $B^*$ is precisely the one given by $\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)\}$ and the abstract inner product induced on $V^*$ is just the one that makes $B^*$ orthonormal.

Note a hidden subtlety. For $f$ (and $g$) to be an isomorphism, one needs to check that it is surjective, which is usually done using the fact that $\dim(V)=\dim(V^*)$. And this fact is proven, given a basis, by constructing a (non-canonical) isomorphism $V\cong V^*$. But once this dimensionality argument has been established, the construction of $f$ and $g$ is completely canonical.

Comment: But the inner product on $V^\star$ is defined by $\langle \eta_1,\eta_2\rangle = \langle f^{-1}(\eta_1),f^{-1}(\eta_2)\rangle$, and hence the resulting map $V^\star \to V^{\star\star}\cong V$ is given by $\eta \mapsto [\xi\mapsto \langle f^{-1}(\eta),f^{-1}(\xi)\rangle]$ thus one cannot construct $f^{-1}$ in terms of it.  That said, on finite-dimensional vector space $f$ is an isomorphism, so its inverse is of course in that sense also canonical.